# Having trouble using decorator within a python scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping, decorator

I've written a script in python to get the links of some posts by tracking a base link from it's landing page. I can scrape the same myself if I stick to the conventional approach.

However, my goal here is to do the same using ***`decorator`***. It seems I'm close but I get stuck when it comes to pass the links from function `get_links()` to `get_target_link()`. I've used `return func()` as a placeholder within function `get_target_link()` as I can't find any idea how to pass the links. There is print statement (works if uncommented) within function `get_links()` to be sure I'm on the right track.

***How can I pass the links `return linklist` from `get_links()` to `get_target_link()` so that I can re-use them if necessary?***

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.janglo.net/component/option,com_sobi2/"

def get_links(func):
    linklist = []
    res = requests.get(func())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".sobi2ItemTitle a"):
        linklist.append(urljoin(url,item.get("href")))
    #print(linklist)
    return linklist

    def get_target_link():
        return func()  #All I need to do is fix this line
    return get_target_link

@get_links
def get_info():
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#sobi2CatListSymbols .sobi2SubcatsListItems a[title]"):
        if items.text=="Tutors":
            ilink = f"{urljoin(url,items.get('href'))}"
    return ilink

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for links in get_info():
        print(links)
```

***`Post Script: I only would like to comply with the logic I've tried to apply above`.***

Update for @sir Andersson (`Can you explain how you want to re-use them if necessary`):

```
def get_target_link():
    titles = []
    new_links =  func()
    for new_link in new_links:
        res = requests.get(new_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
        titles.append(soup.select_one("h1").text)
    return titles
return get_target_link
```

I wanted to create the decorated funtion to act like the following @Carlos Mermingas:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.janglo.net/component/option,com_sobi2/"

def get_info(link):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#sobi2CatListSymbols .sobi2SubcatsListItems a[title]"):
        if items.text=="Tutors":
            ilink = f"{urljoin(url,items.get('href'))}"
    return ilink

def get_links(tlink):
    linklist = []
    res = requests.get(tlink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".sobi2ItemTitle a"):
        linklist.append(urljoin(url,item.get("href")))
    return linklist

def get_target_link(link):
    titles = []
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    titles.append(soup.select_one("h1").text)
    return titles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    item = get_info(url)
    for nlink in get_links(item):
        for ititle in get_target_link(nlink):
            print(ititle)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you want to *re-use them if necessary*? You want to re-use variable defined in decorator? Why not just to make separate function that returns this links list?

Comment: Why do you have to or want to use a decorator? Maybe if you post the "conventional approach" that is working for you will clarify your intention. Also, I see a couple of problems with your current `get_links` implementation: 1) it calls the decorated function twice (`func()`) and 2) it returns a list instead of a callable (`return linklist`).

Comment: Check out the update @sir Andersson.

Comment: Question edited to show my intention @Carlos Mermingas.

Comment: Thank you for posting your original code. It's still unclear to me how a decorator solves a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of a long post, I'll be honest, I've stopped reading at your first python error.

Let me fix it for you, and you tell me if that was what was missing. This is how the decorator pattern works in python.

It is a bit weird at first, its a bit like the shipping ship shipping shipping ships, but its pretty clever.

A decorator is function that returns a function to be called instead of another.

Lets imagine this function, not decorated.

```
>>> def some_func(number):
...      return f'Number is {number}'
...
>>> print(some_func(10))
Number is 10
```

To decorate this function, lets say we're adding fuzzing; common thing to add some delay here and there.

```
>>> def fuzz():
...     def fuzz_decorator(func):
...         def fuzz_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...             print('fuzz') # this is our added functionality
...             return func(*args, **kwargs) # call whatever we're decorating
...         return fuzz_wrapper
...     return fuzz_decorator
...
>>> @fuzz()
... def some_func(number):
...     return f'Number is {number}'
...
>>> print(some_func(10))
fuzz
Number is 10
```

`fuzz()` is a function that returns a function that accepts a function `fuzz_decorator(func)`, and returns a new function that adds some functionality to `func`, while calling `func` itself at some point.

Hoping this isn't confusing. But you got it wrong.

Comment: I found the same example (what you have provided above) in different palces and I've already gone them through. What I tried is implemented the same within my above scraper in real-life but still can't figure out to make it successful @Pedro Rodrigues. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Take it into parts. 1. fuzz, the decorator, returns a function. 2. the function returned before, accepts your function, and returns a different function in place of it. 3. The function returned in place of yours, accepts the same arguments as yours (*args, **kwargs does that), and calls you function inside it. You can follow the function definitions in the code as 1., 2., and 3.

Comment: the number 10 passed in the function call, is available to fuzz_wrapper as args[0], as it was passed to some_func; if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm real close to what I wanted to achieve. The site in my above post throws connection error so I used `stackoverflow.com` instead.
What my script does is collect all the links to various posts from its landing page and then fetch title of each posts from its inner page.

***The following code is fully functional***:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

def get_links(func):

    def get_target_link(*args):
        titles = []
        for link in func(*args):
            res = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
            title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] a").text
            titles.append(title)
        return titles
    return get_target_link

@get_links
def get_info(*args):
    ilink = []
    res = requests.get(*args)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        ilink.append(urljoin(url,items.get('href')))
    return ilink

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_info(url):
        print(item)
```

***One question I could not find any solution of. Ain't there anything productive I can do within the quoted block between the functions below?***

```
def get_links(func):
    ###why this area is for? Can I not do anything here as well?
    #### And print that within "get_target_link()" function?
    def get_target_link():
```